# open command partially not working in tmux in MacOS

Tags: macos, tmux

When inside a tmux session on the local computer, a command:

```
open "https://www.google.com"
```

opens a url in the default browser.

However, when trying to open a file using an app:

```
open -a Preview ./picture.png
```

open produces no error message, but fails to open the file.

When I replicate the same command in Terminal app, picture.png opens as expected in Preview app.

I have read about a similar problem here: ["open" command doesn't work properly inside tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404944/open-command-doesnt-work-properly-inside-tmux) , however, my problem is different as there is no error output and also, reattach-to-user-namespace is now obsolete.

Anyone knows how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?